# get RatingBar value while sliding

Tags: android, ratingbar

I would like to read rating bar value while sliding to change text rating value (poor,nice etc) Im using `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` for this, but it works after user release the finger from bar. I tried `onDragListener` as well but without success.
For sure I have `android:isIndicator="false"` in xml, but no change.

Is there any other listener, code for getting rating instantly - as stars are redrawed correctly while sliding.
Thanks in advance

Roman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to extend `RatingBar`, override `onTouchEvent()` and check for `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` events.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isPressed()) {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float THRESHOLD = 1.0;
                if (Math.abs(x - prevX) > THRESHOLD) {
                   getProgress(); // Now compare with previous progress
                }
                prevX = x;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain in detail how to use this

Answer (score 1):

That code prints on Log cat the current value of rating while, it's sliding.

```
final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);

ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.d("LOG", String.format("%f", ratingBar.getRating());

                }
            return false;
        }
});
```